# Oculus Rift VR with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, virtual-reality, oculus

I have the Oculus Rift VR and I downloaded the SDK from their website. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Pro, and I did all they mentioned in the WIKI page
Minimal Oculus Application Tutorial.

I added the lib files and all the things they said. But I'm getting 
a lot of errors when I add the line `#include "OVR.h"`

it doesn't find all the header files they have in this file. even though I did 
all they mentioned TWICE!

any help?

Comment: have you put the root of SDK include folder in your vs studio global path or in your project settings?

Comment: in my project settings, I did as they mentioned in their website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the problem was that some VS files were missing somehow.. so I installed Visual Studio again.
the missing files were "math.h" and etc.. so the problem was from visual studio.. not from the Oculus SDK.

hope this will help you too..